# The number of integers between 10000 and 100000 with exactly two equal digits

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of integers between 10000 and 100000 (inclusive) with exactly two equal digits.

I thought of writing it as 1abcd. If one a,b,c,d is 1 then there is 9 ways of selecting the first of the remaining three digits, 8 ways for the second, and 7 ways for the third. So in total 24. Now I consider abcd. If a = b, there are 24 ways of selecting b, c and d. And again 24 if a = b, similarly 24 if b = c. I'm pretty sure my reasoning is messed up here, so I'm going to stop (because I excluded 1 from the possibilities, and we could have say a = b = 1, which I don't know how to deal with).

Could someone please show me the proper way to do the question?

Comment: so you want a pair and then $3$ different digits?

Comment: @benji It has to contain exactly two equal digits. 11100 counts, for example.

Comment: If that's the case then my answer below isn't correct

Comment: @Phill Am I right in saying it's correct for a pair then 3 distinct digits? It's helpful to me still, so thank you!

Comment: My interpretation of "exactly two equal" means that you can't have three, four or five equal digits. That means that 11100 would not be valid because it has a set of three, and 11002 would not be valid because it has two sets of two equal digits.

Comment: @Phill You're right actually. I think part of my difficulty with the question was misunderstanding it. I'll study your answer. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, happy to help

Comment: @Phill I had the same interpretation as you. I am not sure if $11100$ counts or not. In my answer I assumed it didn't..

Comment: @benji, just comparing our answers, we're getting very close but slightly different answers.we agree on the number of ways when 0 is repeated, but not for the rest. I'm going to double check my approach

Comment: @Phill if 0 is not repeated you may be counting cases where it appears first which is invalid

Comment: Ah yes, I neglected that, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that there is a "proper way". There will definately be easier and harder ways.
But anyway, I would approach this by looking at the number of ways to choose 5 numbers with exactly two equal, then permuting these to all their possible orders.

$(x,x,a,b,c)$ is the set of numbers to permute. This only represents the *set* of numbers, it *does not* mean that we are only looking at the number $xxabc$. Later on, when we permute, this set will represent all possible ways of ordering $(x,x,a,b,c)$. for instance, $xxabc,axxbc,xbcax$ etc.The symbol $x$ represents the repeated number.

For the first case, we do not include zero because it can't go in the first position, which leaves us with only 9 numbers to choose from.

To fill out a, b and c in all the possible ways is $\binom{8}{3}$. We use 8 instead of 9 because we need to leave a number that $x$ can be. Then we multiply this by the number of ways to order these 5 digits, which is $5!$. Then we divide this by 2 because we don't want to count the two ways that $x$ can be ordered.

There are 9 different ways to choose which value $x$ will have (becasue we are neglecting zero at this point), so we have to multiply by 9.

So by this point we have:

$9*\binom{8}{3}*\frac{5!}{2}$

This covers numbers such as 13325, 66123, 79827 etc.

The next case is for when we have a single zero, which is slightly different because it can't go in the first position. In this case we have 10 numbers to choose from (0,1,...,9)

$(x,x,0,a,b)$ is the set we want to permute. The number of ways to fill out a and b are $\binom{8}{2}$ because we already have chosen two distinct digits. Now, out of the 5 digits, we can place only 4 in the first position (because zero can't go there), then we can place 4 in second, 3 in third etc, so instead of $5!$, in this case we get $4*4*3*2*1=4*4!$

We also have to divide by two because we don't want to count the number of ways that $x$ can be ordered. Then we multiply by 9 because again, the two $x$'s can be any number from 1 to 9.

This covers numbers such as 10233, 11098, 99054 etc.

By this point we have:

$9*\binom{8}{3}*\frac{5!}{2}+9*\binom{8}{2}*\frac{4*4!}{2}$

Now finally for the case when $0$ is the repeated number.

We will ignore the first digit for now. This leaves us with the four digit set $(0,0,a,b)$. There are $\binom{9}{2}$ ways to fill out a and b here. There are $4!$ ways to order these elements. We divide by 2 because we don't want to count the number of ways that 0 can be ordered. By this point, we have chosen 3 distinct numbers with 7 remaining to chose from for the first position. So to count for the different numbers that can take the first position, we multiply by 7.

This covers numbers such as: 10023, 98700, 20980 etc.

All together this gives a total of:

$\binom{9}{2}*\frac{4!}{2}*7+9*(\binom{8}{3}*\frac{5!}{2}+\binom{8}{2}*\frac{4*4!}{2})=45360$

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going through this. This is probably stupid question, but where is the case of 13325 covered for example?

Comment: So the particular case of 13325 is covered by the term $9*\binom{8}{3}*\frac{5!}{2}$. I will edit my answer slightly to try and clear that up.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I appreciate this.

Comment: I think I understand. The number $\binom{8}{3}*\frac{5!}{2}$ wouldn't change because in each case apart from the case $0$ we are doing exactly the same thing we were doing for the case where 1 is repeated. Is this right?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly right :)

Comment: Thank you very much for all of this! :)

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes that exactly $2$ equal digits means that there is a digit appearing twice and then $3$ other distinct digits.

If $0$ is the digit that appears twice then you have $6$ options how to place the zeros. Once you placed them you have $7\cdot 8\cdot 9$ options to choose and arrange the other $3$ digits.

If the digit that appears twice is not $0$ then you have $9$ options for that digit. Now there are $2$ options.
Option 1 - One digit from that pair appears as the most significant digit in which case there are $4$ options remaining for the other digit from the pair and again $7\cdot 8\cdot 9$ options to choose and arrange the other $3$ digits.
Or option 2 - The digit that appears twice does not appear as the most significant in which case there are $6$ options for that pair, then $8$ options to choose the most significant (because it can't be $0$ and then $7\cdot 8$ options for the remaining $2$ digits.

So in total we have:
$$
6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 + 9(4 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 + 6 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 8) = 45360
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I'd +1 answers, but I don't have enough privileges :(